# Can I create a mobile app wrapper around a web app using React Native, similar to what Cordova does to create mobile apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cordova

This is a high-level question and I'm looking for directional guidance before I dive deeper.

I have a web app written in react. My next step is to develop a mobile app across iOS/Android, and my original plan was to learn React Native and rewrite my app. However, learning RN will take time, and re-writing the app in RN completely will definitely take significant amount of time and effort.

My plan is to do so eventually, but my priority is speed over quality for now, and I was wondering if there is a much faster way to ship. So, is there a way to create a mobile app wrapper around my entire web app, similar to what Cordova does?

I am wondering if something like creating  tag wrapper in App.js and then load my web app inside it using web view. (New to programming. Don't be too harsh. :)) Any advice will be welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: react-native is not just a container which renders js,html it uses half (or more) native, like cyborgs in movies half-human half-machine. So if you just load web-view you won't use that native parts which are so important, like gesture handling, gpu performance, memory optimization and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use : [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) or [react-native-htmlview](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview), depend on what you need.

But rumors says it will be block by app stores if there was web-views which using for SEO faking requests and etc, i don't know.